# Meaning of the sql query

Tags: mysql

Hello can someone help me to explain what this coding mean? Tanks

```
 SELECT borrow.*, patrons.*
            FROM borrow
            LEFT JOIN patrons ON patrons.patron_ID = borrow.patron_ID
            WHERE (patrons.studylevel='$studylevel' AND 
            borrow.patron_ID=patrons.patron_ID AND 
            borrow.status='0' AND patrons.patron_Phone=' ')
            AND borrow.due_Date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +1 DAY)
            ORDER BY patrons.studylevel;
```

Comment: Read up on some mysql tutorials, a good starting point is w3schools.com

SELECT, JOINS, WHERE CLAUSE, ORDER BY. hope this helps!

Comment: @Harry w3schools is probably not the best source to use.

Comment: It's not the best source, but it's a good starting point where things are explained quite well with examples. I found it helpful when I first started.@admdrew

Comment: Note that the left join is redundant because the where clause restricts rows to patrons.studylevel='$studylevel' and patrons.patron_Phone=' ' which removes any nulls from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

This query will:

1. Take all records from `borrow` where the `status` is `0` and the `due_date` is tomorrow.
2. Add to it any record from `patrons` where the `patron_id` is a match between the two tables, and the `studylevel` of the patron is `$studylevel` and the `patron_phone` is a space.
3. It will output all fields from both tables where those conditions pass.

It also has a redundant bit in the WHERE clause that is already covered in the FROM clause. You could remove `AND bottom.patron_id = patrons.patron_id` and it will not affect the results of the query.

Comment: tq for helping me explain the query :)

Comment: I have another question if(isset($_SESSION['patron_ID'])){
set_time_limit(0);

include 'dbconnect.php';

 $studylevel1 = $_POST['studylevel'];
 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  
  do
  {
  $senderid = $_SESSION['patron_ID'];
  $studylevel1 = $_POST['studylevel']; what is this coding mean ? I have little bit confuse..

Comment: Best to ask that in a seperate question on stackoverflow.com. I have a good idea of what that bit of PHP does, but being a different code base than the original question, it's unrelated enough to warrant another question. Also, the answer could get a little lengthy and is probably not best for comments.

Comment: best to break your code down into small steps and then try to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This query is to Find the details of the the book borrowed I hope 
Left join is used to join the tables allowing all rows from left table(matched and unmatched)
You can go through the links for on clause, nested query . Date_Add function returns the date the book was with the person. Try out the same with a set of data .you have 8 columns

Comment: tq anirudh for helping me :)